# C# Pass by ref under the hood is it really pass by reference?

Tags: c#, .net

```
void Method(ref int refArgument)
{
    refArgument = refArgument + 44;
}

int number = 1;
Method(ref number);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Under the hood, what is really happening?

It passes the memory address to the method/function and changes the value stored in that memory address?

OR

It creates a new memory address and stores the value in that newly created address and points the variable(number) to the new memory address?

Which is which?

My hunch is the first one since primitive data types in C# are struct and therefore they will always be pass by value

Comment: Why not look at the generated assembly and see?  Also, why the question? Is it purely academic or are you thinking of using the knowledge for 'performance' or other reasons?

Comment: [`ldloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloca_s), [`ldind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldind_i4). LINQPad is your friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the ref keyword work (in terms of memory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569126/how-does-the-ref-keyword-work-in-terms-of-memory)

Comment: If you are asking 'is `number` updated when you assign to `refArgument`, or only when `Method` finishes?' the answer is the former.

Comment: Thanks ya'll I thought it was creating a new memory address and stores the result to that memory address and changes the address pointed at by variable(number), just like in C/C++ it changes the pointer, I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we have a look at the IL code of your snippet:

```il
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  nop         
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0003:  stloc.0     // number
// Loads the address of the local variable at a specific index onto the evaluation stack, short form. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloca_s?view=netframework-4.7.2
IL_0004:  ldloca.s    00 // number
IL_0006:  call        g__Method|0_0
IL_000B:  nop         
IL_000C:  ldloc.0     // number
IL_000D:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0012:  nop         
IL_0013:  ret         

g__Method|0_0:
IL_0000:  nop   
// ldarg.0 called twice: 1. for ldind.i4 and 2. to store the result back to the memory location in stind.i4      
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldarg.0     
// Loads a value of type int32 as an int32 onto the evaluation stack indirectly. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldind_i4?view=netframework-4.7.2
// --> It used the passed intptr
IL_0003:  ldind.i4    
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.s    2C 
IL_0006:  add        
// Stores a value of type int32 at a supplied address. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stind_i4?view=netframework-4.7.2
IL_0007:  stind.i4    
IL_0008:  ret
```

So it:

1. `ldind.i4` loads the value from the supplied memory address and Pushes it onto the stack
2. `ldc.i4.s    2C` loads 44 onto the stack
3. `add` Does your addition with the two elements of the stack
4. `stind.i4` Stores the result of the addition back to the memory address

Comment: I thought it was something like this

1. Loads the value from the supplied memory address
2. Pushes it onto the stack
3. Does your addition on the stack
4. Creates a new memory address
5. Stores the result to that new memory address
6. Points the variable to the new memory address




**or** this thinking does not make any sense at all? 
thank you for explaining the answer you posted because I cant seem to understand it without your explaination

Comment: Therefore in the `ldarg.0` is called twice in the biginning of the method, so the memroy address is still present for `stind.i4`