# C# What is the correct diagram when you reference an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Todo
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public static void ObjectSwap(ref Todo a, ref Todo b)
        {
            Todo taskTemp = a;
            a = b;
            b = taskTemp;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Todo taskOne = new Todo{ Id = 1, Name = "One" };
            Todo taskTwo = new Todo{ Id = 2, Name = "Two" };

            ObjectSwap(ref taskOne, ref taskTwo);    
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone show me the diagram of this code? Because I am baffled if it is creating a temp object then point that to the address whatever a is pointing at, then change the pointer of a to b, then b to temp

Something like this?
[image: Diagram A]

**OR**

Is it does not change the address but the content of the address?

[image]

Which of the two seems more logical? I just want to know how does it works under the hood, does it change the pointer or reference or it changes the content inside the reference...

**EDIT**
How about this one? is the diagram for this code correct?

```
public static void swap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    int temp = a; 
    a = b; 
    b = temp;     
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    swap(ref x, ref y);

    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);      

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image: Diagram C]

So the data are changed not the pointer?

Comment: `Todo taskTemp = a;` makes `taskTemp` point to the same address as `a`. It is just another 32/64 bit value on stack with the same address as `a`

Comment: @FCin - who says it's on the stack? It might be in a register :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Even better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. We don't copy the *object* (as shown in both diagrams) and we don't end up with multiple objects with the same identity.

We just have two objects and it's *just* the arrows from the left to the right that are moving around.

I've crossed out some more with Red crosses and added the correct arrows in blue:

[image]

Comment: but if you reference a primitive data type(structs), it doesn't change the memory address but the content of the address(pass by value)? it looks a little ibt like the second diagram  but using int,char,double per say. (correct me if im wrong) unlike objects(classes) which are passed by reference by default, sorry if my english is bad or terminologies

Comment: @IvanApungan - with a value type, the value is stored *inside* the variable (indeed, it's the entire contents of the variable). As such, for those, there are no arrows (references) and nothing on the right hand side of the diagram at all; changing the variable does result in copies.

Comment: I see, so in this case it really is changing the memory address of the object. but in this case -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317484/c-sharp-pass-by-ref-under-the-hood-is-it-really-pass-by-reference?noredirect=1#comment93515983_53317484

It changes the value and return it to the memory address since it is a pass by value(struct) even if you use the keyword ref it is still a pass by value and the memory address will not change

Comment: @IvanApungan - I'm not sure what you're asking now. First, get clear on the fact that we have *variables* and *data*. The data for value types is stored directly in the variables. The data for reference types are also called objects. Their variables contain *references* to the objects. We don't usually refer to memory addresses for variables at all, just for objects.

Comment: @IvanApungan - and we pass by value by default for all types. But be clear that what we pass are the *variables*. Which by necessity for a value type means the data as well, but doesn't mean that for reference types. That's why reference types and value types appear to act differently.

Comment: Can you check the edit I did, based on your explanation that's what I understood... is it correct?  thanks

Comment: @IvanApungan - yes, but. With value types, there's no garbage collection. It's highly probable that `temp` in the `int` case will be stored in a processor register. All that happens after the `Swap` method is run is that any other piece of code is free to use that register and not worry about preserving its previous value. If it didn't go in a register, it went into the "activation record" (commonly, a "stack frame") for that call to the `Swap` method. When execution leaves the `Swap` method, that activation record disappears entirely.

Comment: thank you so much! now I know that based on my first example, the address where the variables are pointing at did change, while on the second example, the data was changed not the address of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Just because I wanted to draw in MSPaint, here's a different way to present the information. This diagram illustrates that the locations and contents of the `Todo` objects in memory don't change. But we do have variables that refer to specific addresses in memory, and the addresses that they refer to **do** change over the course of the program.

[image]

Comment: The urge to join in with MSPaint based answers is high here too.  Maybe stack overflow needs a scratch pad draw facility :D